# Trying to get an out put such as aaabb = a3bb. Gives me error?

Tags: java

I do not know what I did wrong. Am I forgetting something towards the end or what am I missing.

What I am trying to accomplish is the user imputs a string such as: `aaabbcccc` and then it outputs: `a3bbc4`, so any character that has 3 or more characters in it should show the letter then the amount of times it is in the string.

Am I messing up somewhere I do not see or is it just around the end when it goes to give me the output.

TL;DR string input: `aaabbcccc` ouput: `a3bbc4`. Lets user input then gives error when trying to give output.

Run:

```
Enter a string(only lowercase):    aaabb

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at hw9.RunLengthCode.compress(Hw9.java:26)

at hw9.RunLengthCode.getCText(Hw9.java:20)

at hw9.Hw9.main(Hw9.java:55)

C:\Users\extrapcuser\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-
snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RunLengthCode 
{
    String str1;
    String cText;
    String pText;

    public String setPText(String str) 
    {
        pText = str.toLowerCase();
        return pText;
    }
    public String getCText() 
    {
        compress(cText);
        return cText;

    }
    public void compress(String str) 
    {
        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < str1.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str1.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(i-1))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if(count >= 3)
            {
                String stra = str.substring(0, i-count);
                String strb = str.substring(i-count+1, i-count+2);
                String strc = str.substring(i);
                str = stra + strb + count + strc;
                count = 1;
                i=1;
            }
        }
        if(count >= 3)
        {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length()-count+1);
        }
        cText = str;
    }
}

public class Hw9 
{
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          RunLengthCode rLc = new RunLengthCode();

          System.out.print("Enter a string(only lowercase):    ");
          String pText = in.nextLine();

          rLc.setPText(pText);
          System.out.println(rLc.getCText());
      }
}
```

Comment: You should be a bit more explicit in what the error is. I think you get a `NullPointerException` because you never initialize `str1` and in the `for`-loop in `compress(..)` you access it.

Comment: Edited I apologize for not including the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following flaws in the code.

1. The reason for `NullPointerException` is you didn't initialize the
   String str1. and you are accessing the null reference. so obviously
   throw the NullPointerException
2. cText variable is never initialized.
3. compress method logic will not give you the expected output, and you compare only the adjacent characters.

I would prefer to use the `HashMap` to find the duplicate characters in the `String`.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DuplicateCharactersInString {

```
static LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> charMap = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string(only lowercase):    ");
    String pText = in.nextLine();
    pText = pText.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < pText.length(); i++) {
        if (charMap.containsKey(pText.charAt(i))) {
            charMap.put(pText.charAt(i), charMap.get(pText.charAt(i)) + 1);
        } else {
            charMap.put(pText.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }

    if (!charMap.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character character : charMap.keySet()) {
            int value = charMap.get(character);
            if (value > 2) {
                builder.append(character);
                builder.append(value);
            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
                    builder.append(character);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(builder);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter the string");
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
Enter a string(only lowercase):    aaabbbcccccd
```

a3b3c5d

Comment: you sir are amazing i have to learn some of the things you used here since im still sorta new to java but thank you for the help!